# Plotting rmathematical functions as part of an android application, Is it possible?

Tags: java, android

My goal is to develop a java version of my already existing MATLAB GUI. What my GUI actually does for the most part is plotting mathematical functions upon a pair of x,y axes using 2D plotting functions. Data is inserted by edit boxes and plot buttons are used to activate the functions.

Having a function y=y(x) then a simple command like plot(x,y) will do the job, where x and y are some kind of arrays. Seems like what MATLAB does so simply and accurately (that´s what it was designed for), requires a bit more effort by the Java.

Googling around has led me to OpenGL for 2D graphics. But, still graphics is not what I THINK I need. What I am seeking is plot classes and methods.

So my question is whether there is a simple way to depict math functions inside a pair of axes, which could be a layout view in the case of android apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've said, Java does not have all of the internal math-related functionality of Matlab. You will have to implement this yourself.. meaning actually draw the graph points on some sort of graphical canvas.

Fortunately, many other people have had this requirement before, and ended up creating libraries that do this for you.

Your task is, then, to find the best suited library for your needs, and use it.

Some pointers on where to start looking: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424752/any-good-graphing-packages-for-android

Comment: That was fast!
It seems like that is the java way. Find the best suited libraries to cover one´s needs.
Thank you!

Comment: and if you don't find a library and end up implementing something from scratch, be community-friendly and publish your own code as a library ;)

Comment: Take a look at this one too: http://jwork.org/jhepwork/android/ They have an Anroid app you can download and play with, and they say which libraries they've used in making it. Might be a bit overkill for your needs though

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer to this question in a few days, you can do this by using the green checkmark on the side

Comment: This is not a full answer. Your link is currently down!